# ObjectInputStream over DeflaterInputStream throws StreamCorruptedException

Tags: java, serialization, gzip, deflate

I'm trying to use `ObjectOutputStream` over a `DeflaterOutputStream` to write deflated data into an underlying stream. But when I try to read the data with their `InputStream` counterparts, an exception is thrown. It is worth of note that replacing `Deflate{Output,Input}Stream` with `GZip{Output,Input}Stream`, it works as expected. An example code that shows this behavior can be seen below:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(baos))) {
    oos.writeObject("test");
}

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
try(ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new DeflaterInputStream(bais))) {
    System.out.println(oos.readObject());
}
```

It throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 789CAB98
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

Does anyone know why exacly this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I've already figured it out and it is a silly mistake. But answering my own question so future people don't fall for it again:

The inverse class of `DeflaterOutputStream` is `InflaterInputStream`, not `DeflaterInputStream`. So the code should look like the one below:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new DeflaterOutputStream(baos))) {
    oos.writeObject("test");
}

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
try(ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(bais))) {
    System.out.println(oos.readObject());
}
```